# Error when running Cucumber Junit test :Intializationerror

Tags: java, selenium, exception, junit, cucumber

I'm trying to run cucumber test,but i'm getting the following exception. I used those jars with their versions

[image]

And this is my project :

[image]

And this is testRunner class code :

```
    package cucumberTest;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "Feature"
        ,glue={"stepDefinition"}
        )

        public class TestRunner {

        }
```

In the logIn.feature file :

Feature: Login Action Test

Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
    Given User is on Home Page
    When User Navigate to LogIn Page
    And User enters UserName and Password
    Then Message displayed Login Successfully

Scenario: Successful LogOut
    When User LogOut from the Application
    Then Message displayed LogOut Successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java/1.2.5), cucumber-java-1.2.5 requires gherkin-2.12.2, while I was  providing gherkin-4.1.13

So I downloaded version 2.12.2 from [here](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cgherkin), removed version 4.1.13 and  it worked for me (I did a clean to the project).

Answer (score 0):

I'm new and still learning. I had a similar 'cucumber runner initialization error' message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

[Referenced Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmU7k.png) <= My Jars when I was having an error. I then replaced my cucumber-junit-1.1.5.jar with cucumber-junit-1.2.2.jar and the error message is now resolved. I can now run my cucumber junit test.
I started with the latest jars but they seems to have issues. I then tried several different combination. I read 'rule of thumb' that the three jars (-core, -java and -junit) need to be of same version. Only then I was able to run my feature files and junit tests.

My current working jars are:

```
gherkin-2.12.2
cucumber-core-1.2.2
cucumber-java-1.2.2
cucumber-junit-1.2.2
cucumber-html-0.2.3
cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3
hamcrest-all-1.3
junit-4.11
selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0
```

I hope this helps.